# Why was Eisav approaching?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, time, vayishlach

Yaakov spends 20 years in the house of Lavan, after which he starts heading home.  He sends messengers ahead to check on his brother Eisav ([Bereishis 32:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8227#v=4)).  The messengers return and inform Yaakov that Eisav is approaching with an army of sorts ([Bereishis 32:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8227#v=7)).

After 20+ years, why was Eisav just now coming, at exactly the moment when Yaakov was leaving?  Did Eisav depart towards Yaakov as a result of the messengers that Yaakov sent to him?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/esav-was-coming-with-400-men-why-then/4157#4157

Answer (score 2):

Lavan sent his son Beor (the father of Bilam) who was 17 years old - with 10 men to let Eisav know that Yaakov was on his way back. Beor also told Eisav how Yaakov fooled his father Lavan just like he fooled Eisav. That got Eisav riled up and he went to greet Yaakov with 400 men. ([Sefer HaYoshor - end of Parshat Vayeitzei](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&pgnum=107))