# Did Lavan notify Eisav that Yaakov was coming?

Tags: yaakov-and-eisav

[Vayishlach 32:7](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/32.7#e0n6)

> (ז) וַיָּשֻׁ֙בוּ֙ הַמַּלְאָכִ֔ים אֶֽל־יַעֲקֹ֖ב לֵאמֹ֑ר בָּ֤אנוּ
> אֶל־אָחִ֙יךָ֙ אֶל־עֵשָׂ֔ו וְגַם֙ הֹלֵ֣ךְ לִקְרָֽאתְךָ֔
> וְאַרְבַּע־מֵא֥וֹת אִ֖ישׁ עִמּֽוֹ׃

I remember that someone says that Lavan had notified Eisav that Yaakov was on his way and that the malachim met Eisav already traveling to meet Yaakov. However, I do not remember who said this and this pasuk does not say so explicitly. Does anyone know if there is such a perush and who would have said so?

טור הפירוש הארוך says

> פי׳ כאשר אתה הולך לקראתו כן הוא הולך לקראתך ומהרה תפגעו זה בזה ולא אמר
> בא לקראתך פי׳ הולך לקבץ חיילותיו ובא לקראתך:

However this does not say if Eisav started towards Yaakov before or after the messengers reached him.

Ibn Ezra is quoted as saying

> וגם הלך לקראתך – שהוגד לו שאתה בא.

But he does not give any details

@Chatzkel says in a comment that [Sefer Hayashar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/esav-was-coming-with-400-men-why-then/4157#4157) says that Lavan sent his son Beor to notify Eisev.

Are there any other meforshim that say this?

Comment: Lavan sent his son Beor (the father of Bilam) who was 17 years old - with 10 men to let Eisav know that Yaakov was on his way back. Beor also told Eisav how Yaakov fooled his father Lavan just like he fooled Eisav. That got Eisav riled up and he went to greet Yaakov with 400 men. (Sefer HaYoshor - end of Parshat Vayeitzei). Taken from this answer. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/esav-was-coming-with-400-men-why-then/4157#4157

Comment: @Chatzkel please post as an answer

Comment: The Ibn Ezra says on the words  וְגַם֙ הֹלֵ֣ךְ לִקְרָֽאתְךָ֔ that the malachim told him that someone told Esav  that you are coming (so therefore he is coming towards you too) but he does not say the person who did so was Lavan

Comment: I saw that but since he did not give details I did not add it to the question. @Schmerel  I copied what AlHatorah.org wrote